# Cors header error when making web api request - works in curl

Tags: server, cors, backend

I'm working with a API connect to a work server I have no access to, run by a team in India for some reason. (We are due an update).

I at least have the documentation to send a correct request.

I believe the server I make a request to, then access's another server to return the data.

Every request I make gets blocked by a cors error. (I'm using JavaScript)

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
> doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
> the requested resource.

I must say I know little to nothing about pre-flight headers, including whats inside it, why its sent and how its sent.

So it makes two requests technically. The first pre-flight request comes back with a status of 200, but then the real request fails and I don't even get a status code.

However if I make the exact same request using CURL, I get the correct response from the server.

So I know cors is cross origin, I make most servers with a list of allowed origins, but like I said I have no access to this server by our Indian team.

I have tried spoofing my origin to curl in the request using burp suite. No effect (possibly did it wrong).

I have been googling round and it seems like I really cannot effect the headers from the client side to solve this issue.

So now I turn off all security in my Chrome browser using
`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`.

Now when I make the original request, I GET the response I have been expecting and everything works.

So I'm confused if this is real a server or client side issue, and I would love to figure out how to solve this or convince my regular browser to accept the results as if it had its security turned off.

I'm really not sure what I should try next.

I make a axios post request using this code

```js
const [requestData, setRequestData] = useState({
    authentication: {
      id: 'work_api',
      password: password, // This will initially be undefined
    },
    method: {
      method_name: 'get_api_settings',
      parameters: {}
    },
  });
```

If I convert that to curl it works!
Taking off the pre-flight requirement has no effect.

```js
  getData: (path, data) => {
    return axios.post(path, data, { withCredentials: true} );
  },
```

Any tips or ideas would be hugely appreciated.

This is my working curl request:

```bash
curl -vv -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"authentication\": {\"id\": \"sos_api\",\"password\": \"12345678\"},\"method\": {\"method_name\": \"get_api_settings\",\"parameters\": {}}}" https://api.....com/
*   Trying 35.82.175.40:443...
* Connected to api.... (35...) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* using HTTP/1.1
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.silhouettedesignstore.com
> User-Agent: Chrome/101.0.0.0.
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 155
>
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 07 Dec 2023 11:43:23 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: silh_api_uuid=9eb69288-3c84-49f8-96fd-0b2cbbbb18ca; expires=Fri, 06-Dec-2024 11:43:23 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/
< Set-Cookie: silh_api_uuid=9eb69288-3c84-49f8-96fd-0b2cbbbb18ca; expires=Fri, 06-Dec-2024 11:43:23 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/
< Cache-Control: max-age=864000
< Expires: Sun, 17 Dec 2023 11:43:23 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< Content-Length: 90
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
{"success":false,"status_code":"401","msg":"id\/password invalid\/not supplied","data":[]}* Connection #0 to host api.silhouettedesignstore.com left intact
```